# Hide part of map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

Cont. on [Distance between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093318/google-map-api-distance-between-2-locations)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
var map;

function initialize() 
{    
    directionsDisplay= new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var mapProp = 
    {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('textDirection'));

}

function showMap()
{
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("textDirection").style.display = 'inline';
    var start = document.getElementById('origin').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
    var directionsRequest = 
    {
        origin : start,
        destination : end,
        travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }

    directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status)
    {
        if(status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {  
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);          
        }
        else
        {
            window.alert('Cannot'); 
        }
    });
}

function resetMap()
{
    document.getElementById("origin").value = '';
    document.getElementById("destination").value = '';
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("textDirection").style.display = 'none';
}  
</script>

<style>
#textDirection{
width: 300px;
height: 60%;
float: right;
overflow-y: auto;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-right: 29%;
}

#googleMap{
width : 50%;
height : 60%;
top: 5%;
position : absolute;
margin-left: 5px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<form action="showmap1.php" method="post">
From: <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin" size="30" />&nbsp;
To:<input type="text" name="destination" id="destination" size="30" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="showMap()" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetMap()" /><br />
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<div id="textDirection"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

From above code, I have following questions:
(1) **JavaScript**
    When I run the above code, I get the output like the below image:
 [image]

The gray part is the map displayed. I want to hide it when I first run the page. How should I modify it?
(2) **JavaScript**
    After I search a correct result, now I try to search a blank destination. It shows the below image:
[image]

However, the previous map and route are show together with alert. My expected output is only show the alert message "Cannot" with no map and route. How should I modify it?

(3) **CSS**
When I zoom my web page into 120%, my output is like below image:
[image]
Oh my god, i can't see the route. It is more even worst if I zoom my web page bigger and bigger. Why and how should I modify it in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)**

you should put

```
var mapProp = 
{
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 62, lng: -110.0},
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

into `showMap()` function. Map would not show at the first time load page. It only show when you press `Search` button.

**(2)**

If show `Cannot` alert, hide the map and route as following:

```
if(status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
{  
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);          
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("textDirection").style.display = 'none';
    window.alert('Cannot');
}
```

**(3)**

If you ues `float:right`, should not fix the `width` of element. If the `width` of elements is larger than screen, it will break your layout. I am not good at `CSS`, you could try the following code. Hope this help ^^

```
#textDirection{
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    float: right;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

#googleMap{
    width : 50%;
    height : 60%;
    top: 5%;
    position : absolute;
    margin-left: 5px; 
}
```

**Update:**

To hide the map and only show when you need, please using event:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

I had update my code, please check this. We only need is set zoom of map smaller to 1 and increase it immediately:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
}); 

map.setZoom( map.getZoom() - 1 );
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() + 1 );
```

[Here is updated answer](http://jsfiddle.net/0477zsuj/4/)

Comment: Nice...I have a questions for Q2. I try your fiddle, and I still see the map and route together with alert ("Cannot").

Comment: Nice ^^...But this time the map cannot show the directions from your latest fiddle...

Comment: @KKLMichael: I had updated the answer, hope this help

Comment: Very very nice ^^... You solved my problem... I will understand your code and also learn jQuery as well... Next time if I have a problem I will find you...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to use the google maps API, here is a function to use: Note: you must add &libraries=geometry to your script source

find in [Google Maps - How to get the distance between two point in metre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997627/google-maps-how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-point-in-metre)

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.463688, 9.18814);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0438317, 9.75936230000002);

alert(calcDistance(p1, p2));

//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(p1, p2){
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
}

}
```

also you can use like

```
   var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3584308, -71.0597732);
      var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(42.348805455204214, -71.07485794349975);

      var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
      {
      suppressMarkers: true,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      var request = {
      origin: location1, 
      destination:location2,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
      {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
      {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      //alert("the distance: " + response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
      distance = "The distance between the two points on the chosen route is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
      //distance += "<br/>The aproximative driving time is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
      document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = distance;
      }
      });

      // show a line between the two points
      var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map, 
      path: [location1, location2],
      strokeWeight: 7,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeColor: "#FFAA00"
      });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/39KKu/